# Is a matrix group free?

Tags: gr.group-theory, matrices, free-groups

Let two matrices $P = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 &  0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $S = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ generate a group $G$. Is $G$ free (apart from $P^3 = 1$)?

Comment: Do you mean that they freely generate a free product $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z\ast \mathbb Z$?

Comment: Yes. In other words, are there any non-trivial relations in $G$ involving $S$?

Comment: It's equivalent to ask whether $(S,PSP^{-1},P^{-1}SP)$ freely generate a free group (on 3 generators).

Comment: $S^{-1}P$ has order $4$.

Comment: My previous comment becomes useless in view of Derek's definite answer. However, it's correct and Derek's answer allows to find a relation. Namely writing $T=PST^{-1}$ and $U=P^{-1}SP$, we have $(P^{-1}S)^3=UTS$; since $(P^{-1}S)^4=1$, we have $(P^{-1}S)^{12}=1$, which means that $(UTS)^4=1$, and hence $(S,T,U)$ is not free.

Comment: Of course, @DerekHolt's wise remark begs the question of whether the group is isomorphic to $C_4 \star C_3.$

Comment: @IgorRivin: You mean it *suggests* the question; "begging the question" is a logical fallacy where one assumes the desired conclusion in the hypothesis in order to reach it.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin https://www.google.com/search?q=beg+the+question&rlz=1C1CHZL_enUS757US757&oq=beg+the+question&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2491j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @IgorRivin I agree with Arturo about that - the Wikipedia article in your link gives precisely his definition.

Comment: @IgorRivin https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begging_the_question
I know it is often (mis)used the other way; pet peeve.

Comment: The group $G$ has a common fixed vector, namely $(1,1,1)^t$. This suggests a variable trafo and one can show that $G$ is similar to the group of all matrices of the form $$ \begin{pmatrix} A & b \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $$ with $A\in \operatorname{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$ and $b\in \mathbb{Z}^2$. In particular, $G$ is not the free product on $S^{-1}P$ and $P$.